# uncss, regex pattern for .no-'string', .is-'string'

Tags: javascript, regex, uncss, gulp-uncss

I'm having some regex woes.

Using gulp-uncss

I'd like to add some classes to the ignore option.

Any class that starts with .no-

Any class that contains .is-

```
.no-flexbox {}
.test.is-active {}
.test .is-hidden {}


.pipe(uncss({
    html: ['tmp/public_html/*.html'],
    ignore: ['/(.is-)(\w)*', '(.no-)(\w)*']
}))
```

This isn't quite right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexes look incomplete. May be you should do like this

```
.pipe(uncss({
    html: ['tmp/public_html/*.html'],
    ignore: ['/\.no-\w+/g', '/\.\w+\s?\.is-\w+/g']
}))
```

Comment: Perfect... Just removed the surrounding apostrophe, and boooom... Many thanks

Comment: Yes, removing surrounding apostrophes makes the above code snippet work.